# Looking for aid in a project

Tags: first-robotics

I'm starting a project and it's my hardest yet I'm dipping my toe in to robotics by creating a odradek from the game  death stranding I've laid out what the plans should look like and now I'm trying to see what I'm actually supposed to do now. I know I need a Arduino , a LED and a few dc motors but the kind of motors I need I can't seem to find any like it. Reminder I've never done something like this before and having a helping hand would be great just some one who can point me in the right direction. 
I can send a concept Sketch

Comment: you have not said anything about what you expect the Arduino and the motors to do ... your post is missing the `robotics` part

Comment: Although it was a very anticipated game I don't think many of us know which system you want to build. Adding more references would work, plus the comments from jsotola.